# How to determine enabled legend items in Kendo-UI bar chart?

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm using a stacked bar chart in v2013.2.726 of kendo-ui. I would like to base a grand total calculation off of the enabled items in the chart's legend. So far I have not found a consistent way to tell which legend items are enabled.

I tried the following but it does not work because kendoChart._sourceSeries[i].visible does not consistently match the visual state after multiple clicks on legend items.

```
function onLegendItemClick(clickEventArgs) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < self.kendoChart._sourceSeries.length; ++i) {
        if ((clickEventArgs.text === self.kendoChart._sourceSeries[i].name &&
            !self.kendoChart._sourceSeries[i].visible) ||
            (clickEventArgs.text !== self.kendoChart._sourceSeries[i].name &&
            self.kendoChart._sourceSeries[i].visible)) {
            total += chartModel.Series[i].Total; 
        }
    }
    ...
};
```

So is it even possible to determine which legend items are enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I started looking into implementing something to track the item state outside of kendo. It was only then I noticed the property kendoChart.options.series[i].visible which does indicate the state.

My apologies for answering my own question but there was not much traffic to it or the question I posted on the kendo-ui forum. So I figured I should share what I found.

Comment: Answering your own question is completely valid and actually encouraged. Of course if another person comes up with a better answer then tick theirs. No need to apologise.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can to loop through the visible (active) elements that are being displayed in the Kendo chart and then display that Total.

Instead of searching which items are active you can directly get them through the [dataSource.view()](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-view) method.

Comment: That sounds good. Unfortunately, dataSource.view() can only be used in the change event handler or fetch() method. In my click handler the view has a length of zero.